# 2 different joins through 2 different columns

Tags: sql, postgresql

On my database I have 2 tables that register when and which items have been added to 2 different lists. They look something like this:

- list1: id, time (timestamp), item_id (int4)
- list2: id, time (timestamp), item_id (int4)

The items on each of the lists can appear multiple times (as many as they have been added on the list). They come from the sale set of items (an item can be added to both lists).

With SQL (postgresql) I want to join both lists per day (date, I don't care about the exact time) and per item (the same item_id should only appear once per day, but they could appear again on the next day).

I've tried with multiple types of join but nothing worked! How could I do that?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using two separate tables, instead of one table with a "type" column?

In any case, use `union all`:

```
select time::date, item_id, count(*)
from ((select id, time, item_id, 1 as which
       from list1
      ) union all
      (select id, time, item_id, 2 as which
       from list2
      )
     ) l
group by time::date, item_id;
```

Comment: You are really a kind man. Helping other without any expectations of upvote and mark answers.. Claps for you